# Position of English text in Hebrew changes while fetching from DB

Tags: java, sql, right-to-left

I have some Hebrew texts in DB. The texts are a combination of Hebrew and English. In the DB I have text `ABC-מברך אותך על תמיכה במוצר`, in the java code I get the text as `מברך אותך על תמיכה במוצר - ABC`. Encoding is UTF-8. 
Is there any way I can get the text as is in the java code.

Query used to fetch the data :

```
SELECT  * from ACT_TRANSLATION_CONSOLE ACT WHERE ACT.KEY_IDENTIFIER LIKE 'key1'
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the first character in the Java string? Is it `A` or `מ`?

Comment: @AlexCohn  first character in the String is "ה" but expected character is 'A'. Java reads the text as RTL until it reaches English text , English text is misplaced in the String

Comment: You mix the storage order and the visual order. There is no way **String.charAt(0)** will produce `ה`. If I understand correctly, in your case it's `מ`. And you want your Java string to be displayed right-to-left. The question is, how do you display this string? And don't be worried how it looks in debugger. I mean, there are ways to force the debugger to show the expected direction, but usually it's not worth effort, as long as the final result is correct.